# How to make class or function to create log file and write in Python?

Tags: python, file, code-generation, logging

I am new learner to Python, so I am not getting how to make common function for creating log file to record each and every details during testing...

Comment: As you're a new learner I'm going to tell you ahead of time that you should be using `logging` instead.

Comment: record each n evry details ... pretty good on chat window but you will do very well if you can avoid that here.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html). If that's overkill for you, why not insert `print` statements/functions in relevant places of your code and print the variables you're interested in?